# Reset button doesn't clear the default date in the inputtext box

Tags: jsf

In my managed bean class, i have 2 variables as fromDate and toDate of type java.util.Date. I made the fromDate as an inputText box in jsp so user can enter. In  toDate i have an inputText box which has a default value of current Date.
private Date toDate = new Date();

I hav written a reset method inside the MB class having
this.fromDate = null;
this.toDate =null;

on invoking reset method through reset button in the jsp , Only fromDate which I enter is getting cleared. ToDate shows current date without getting cleared.